# How to check if the user should be assigned the role admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

The goal of this method is to check when a user signs up, if they are on the list of users that should be admins.

I am new to Ruby and think it is just a syntax error:

```
  def set_role
    if self[:email] == ("email@gmail.com" || "sample@gmail.com" || "test@gmail.com")
        self[:role] = "admin" 
    else
      self[:role] = "customer"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good time to use a `case` statement:

```
def set_role
  self[:role] = case self[:email]
                when "email@gmail.com", "sample@gmail.com", "test@gmail.com"
                  'admin'
                else
                  'customer'
                end
end
```

It's easy to add new values to the `when` test.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if an array of emails includes the current email like this:

```
def set_role
  if ["email@gmail.com", "sample@gmail.com", "test@gmail.com"].include?(self[:email])
    self[:role] = "admin" 
  else
    self[:role] = "customer"
  end
end
```

This code could also be improved:

```
def set_role
  admin_emails = ["email@gmail.com", "sample@gmail.com", "test@gmail.com"]
  self[:role] = if admin_emails.include?(self[:email])
    "admin" 
  else
    "customer"
  end
end
```

Comment: I like the latter.. Thanks!